# app-router Store a path segment in a variable Polymer 1.x

Tags: routes, url-routing, polymer-1.0

Hello I'm trying to use app controller on my Polymer app. This is what I have:

```
<app-router>
    <app-route path="/order/:orderId">
        <template>
            <p>Your order number is <span>{{orderId}}</span></p>
        </template>
    </app-route>
</app-router>
```

But I get this in my browser:

```
Your order number is {{orderId}}
```

I saw this thread: https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router/issues/127

Is there any workaround or something to make this work? 
If not is there other routing elements that use lazy loading like app-router that can be used with Polymer 1.x?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else:

```
<app-route path="/evaluate/:userId" element="evaluation-wrap-element" bindRouter></app-route>
```

just use the element property